# Recognize newline (\n) in text as end of sentence in Spacy

Tags: spacy

I'd like to recognize a newline in text as the end of a sentence. I've tried inputting it into the nlp object like this:

```py
text = 'Guest Blogging\nGuest Blogging allows the user to collect backlinks'
nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
config = {"punct_chars": ['\n']}
nlp.add_pipe("sentencizer", config=config)
for sent in nlp(text).sents:
    print('next sentence:')
    print(sent)
```

The output of this is:

```
next sentence:
Guest Blogging
Guest Blogging allows the user to collect backlinks
```

I don't understand why Spacy isn't recognizing the newline as a sentence end. My desired output is:

```
next sentence:
Guest Blogging:
next sentence:
Guest Blogging allows the user to collect backlinks
```

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason the `sentencizer` isn't doing anything here is that the `parser` has run first and already set all the sentence boundaries, and then the `sentencizer` doesn't modify any existing sentence boundaries.

The `sentencizer` with `\n` is only the right option if you know you have exactly one sentence per line in your input text. Otherwise a custom component that adds sentence starts after newlines (but doesn't set all sentence boundaries) is probably what you want.

If you want to set some custom sentence boundaries before running the parser, you need be sure you add your custom component before the parser in the pipeline:

```py
nlp.add_pipe("my_component", before="parser")
```

Your custom component would set `token.is_start_start = True` for the tokens right after newlines and leave all other tokens unmodified.

Check out the second example here: https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines#custom-components-simple

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by using

```
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm', exclude=["parser"])
    
    text = 'Guest Blogging\nGuest Blogging allows the user to collect backlinks'
    
    config = {"punct_chars": ['\n']}
    nlp.add_pipe("sentencizer", config=config)
    
    for sent in nlp(text).sents:
        print("next sentence")
        print(sent)
```

Output:

```
   next sentence
   Guest Blogging
   
   next sentence
   Guest Blogging allows the user to collect backlinks
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also break sentences by \n before feeding spacy.

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
def get_sentences(_str):
  chunks = _str.split('\n')
  sentences = []
  nlp = English()
  nlp.add_pipe("sentencizer")
  for chunk in chunks:
    doc = nlp(chunk)
    sentences += [sent.text.strip() for sent in doc.sents]
  return sentences
```